# Problem with r.grow.distance on GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, distance

I would like to use r.grow.distance on a raster map. I rasterised a shapefile (about 50 cities in a region) and we can see them on the raster map.

Yet, when I launch r.grow.distance, I have a distance raster map from the entire original raster, and not from the features in my raster map (the cities). I have a big dimension raster map with completely useless distances.

I tried many solutions (resolution, rasterization,...) and nothing worked...

If anyone has a suggestion, it would be great.

Comment: In your cities - input - raster, did all other (non-city) cells are set to null? If not, you should set them to null and run the tool again.

Comment: You can check the count of Null cells with `r.stats -cp <cities_raster>`. Also can you add the outputs of `g.region -p` and `r.info <cities_raster>`

Comment: Please be sure that you have your https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following example is useful. It is in an unprojected Location, i.e.:

```
g.proj -p
XY location (unprojected)

# some arbitrary region
g.region rows=30 cols=30 -p

# generate random vector points
v.random output=random_points npoints=50

# rasterise the points
v.to.rast in=random_points out=random_points use=cat
d.rast random_points
```

[image: A raster map of 50 random points]

*Note, it is likely important to check for NULL cells, exactly as the comments refer after the question.*

```
# compute distances
r.grow.distance in=random_points distance=distance_to_random_points

# display 
d.rast distance_to_random_points
d.vect random_points color=blue size=20 icon=basic/circle fcolor=yellow width=3
```

[image: Distance map to 50 random points generated using r.grow.distance]

Looking a the manual page https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.grow.distance.html, there is a nice example with the legend for the distance raster map and the actual distances shown in a zoomed-id region (using GRASS-GIS' `d.rast.num` module).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

I checked with r.stat the count of Null cells. Everything was fine.

So I did all the process again. I downloaded my shapefile again, I rasterised it once again and I did r.grow.distance once again. And it worked. Yet, I didn't change anything but it worked.

One more thing, I realised the rasterisation from QGis for a r.grow.distance on Grass was not efficient. This is just an information and an advice ! You need to do all the process on Grass.